# When we have multiple windows forms in our C# application, how to make one form as opening form

Tags: c#, winforms

My application has two forms - Login and registration.

I have first coded registration form and when ever I start the application only registration form is coming.
Is there any property I have to change or suggest way.Where I can make Login Form as start up form.

Comment: Go to program.cs file and set the form you want to load at start-up.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Program.cs and you will see

```
Application.Run(new RegistrationForm());
```

change the name of the form to LoginForm as follows:

```
Application.Run(new LoginForm());
```

Full code in Program.cs should look like this:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LoginForm());
    }
}
```

**Note:** Replace LoginForm() with the name of your Form

Comment: Thanks Vishal for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Find Program.cs in your project. It should have `private static void Main(string[] args)` method inside it and something like `Application.Run(new RegistrationForm());`. Change it to `Application.Run(new LoginForm());`

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the quick reply, I am able to run it now.